# Spring Web App Deployment:: how do you hide data in application.properties?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, security, web-deployment

everyone!

this is going to be my first time pushing a newly developed Spring Boot App and I was wondering if there is a way to protect passwords and other sensitive information written in the application.properties file.

Assuming we have the following lines:

```
# PostgreSQL connection settings
spring.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/bdreminder
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
```

The source code is to be first stored on GitHub and having the credentials stored in plain text does not seem to be a good idea.
So, I could probably add the file to the .gitignore one; I could set some environment variables on the host but how would it populate the .properties file afterward? Also, this seems quite cumbersome in terms of the scaling later on.

So, basically, I am trying to see how it is done in a real-life :)

Please, help :)

Answer (score 1):

Simplest option is to create a `profile specific` application.properties file and activate that profile. So for example create `application-private.properties` and activate profile `private`. Of course you have to watch out to not commit this file.

Alternatively, and probably a safer option, is to define a file outside your project and import it in your `application.properties` with following line:

```
spring.config.import=file:../path/to/your/external.properties
```

Comment: thank you. While it works with smaller projects, I wonder if the same approach is used in production for bigger systems.

Comment: so in my last project, which was quite big microservices project, that is what we used locally and on production those values for swapped using environment variables from Kubernetes, exactly like the lower answer suggested. Because Spring overrides property file values with values from environment it works well. But that approach is not applicable to you, as you as a developer most likely won't be the one setting those environment variables or dealing with kubernetes/deployment - devops guys do that.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot has extensive support for [external configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config). The usual approach is to use one of environment variables, configuration provided by a platform such as Kubernetes, or a specialized configuration system through Spring Cloud Config; these all keep secrets (or just environment-specific information) entirely outside of the code. They also have the advantages of providing a common style of configuration for other applications that do not use Spring Boot.

Comment: thank you, I will give it a good reading!